# Use of python progress bar in script

Tags: python

I want to show progress bar in my script because it takes a lots of time to execute while working on huge files.I gone through the [python progressbar module](http://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/)

and examples also its good and very intresting to use but as per examples all values are predefine .As we can't guess the max execution time of programm or function.So i am not able to figure out how should i use progress bar function in my sctipt

```
for data in files:
     crawl_data(data)
```

this is the crawl_data function which take time so how can i set the progress bar values

```
pbar = ProgressBar(widgets=[Percentage(), Bar()], maxval=300).start()
for i in range(300):
    time.sleep(0.01)
    pbar.update(i+1)
pbar.finish()
```

how can i define this range and maxval values in above lines of code.

Comment: You've got to decide on your own scale and work out what the figures mean yourself. Without a lot more information, we can't help.

Comment: i want to say that how can i set the maxval and that range prior execution it should take some delay time as a count something like that i am not sure..

Comment: Set the maxval to the size of the file and increment the position when reading it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I got working.

Stdout

```
Working: | Elapsed Time: 0:00:10
```

Python

```
import time
import progressbar
import threading

def crawl_data(data):
    # sleep for 10 seconds
    time.sleep(10)
# end of def crawl_data

def main():
    data = 'some data'
    widgets = ['Working: ', progressbar.AnimatedMarker(), ' ',
                   progressbar.Timer()]
    pbar = progressbar.ProgressBar(widgets=widgets)
    # creating thread to run crawl_data()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=crawl_data,
                              args=(data,))
    thread.daemon = True
    # starting thread and progress bar
    thread.start()
    pbar.start()
    i = 1
    # continuous loop until crawl_data thread is not alive
    while True:
        # update every second
        time.sleep(1)
        pbar.update(i)
        if not thread.is_alive():
            pbar.finish()
            break
        # end of if thread is not alive
        i += 1
    # end of continuous loop until crawl_data thread is not alive
    # prints a new line
    print
# end of def main

# run main
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't guess the execution time, a progress bar is worthless (remember most of the old MS progress bars?). You are probably looking for something like a activity indicator. Since web2.0 it is common to use something rotating.